# Macro to Send Sheet in email - NOT active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that will send a specified sheet as its own workbook to an email address.  This sheet is NOT the active worksheet.  Basically, I need a page of buttons, and then program each button to send a specific sheet (tab, whatever) within the workbook as an attachment to an email.  Again, the sheet being sent is a different sheet than the sheet containing the button.  Please advise.

Comment: As long as you have a definitive path for each sheet, it should be fairly easy. Will throw up a solution in a second

Answer (score 1):

Right then, its untested but should at least point you in the right direction. If someone else knows what the sendUsing bit refers to then please refresh my memory! (if not, I will try and look through and remember as most of this is code is directly pulled from work I did a year or so ago)

```
Sub copyAndEmail()
Dim sendUsing, smtpServer, smtpPort, pathToWB As String
Dim wbOpen, wbSend As Workbook

sendUsing = "" 'cant remember what this one is actually, but I have it on "2" - will look through some old notes and check
smtpServer = "" 'this is your mail server IP
smtpPort = "" 'and your mail server port

pathToWB = "c:\Your\Sheet\Location.xls"

Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(pathToWB)

wbOpen.Sheets("Your Sheet").Copy

getTemp = Environ$("tmp")
    If getTemp = vbNullString Then
        getTemp = Environ$("temp")
    End If

Set wbSend = ActiveSheet.SaveAs(getTemp & "\" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy_hhmm") & ".xls")

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With objMessage
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = sendUsing
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = smtpPort
    .Configuration.Fields.Update
    .Subject = "" 'Insert Subject Here
    .From = "" 'insert "From" email address
    .To = "" 'insert "To" email address
    .TextBody = "" 'Insert Body Here
    .AddAttachment wbSend ' attachment
    .Send
End With
Kill wbSend

End Sub
```

Comment: Found the explanation. Depending on your email config, you may need to change it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: Is this for sending an outlook email?  SOrry, I should have specified that!

Comment: It makes no difference in this instance. It is possible to create an outlook instance  and send an email from that, but this way should be quicker

Comment: Hmm -- ok some of this feels a little superfluous, but that might just be my ignorance!  I'm putting the button in the workbook that contains the sheet I want to send -- I have buttons in place that will send the active sheet, that works fine -- but I guess I'm trying to figure out how to send a different sheet... I'm not tweaking my macro right... I may post it for help later.

Comment: Is it a sheet in the same workbook that you need to send? If so, you can eliminate the need for opening the workbook initially and just start with copying the sheet. Some of it may be superfluous for your needs but was going with a broader overview to try and anticipate any possible needs